# Problemas al intentar obtener la fecha correcta con Date() y moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Necesito convertir una fecha inicialmente dada mediante un string con formato "dd/mm/yyyy" a una fecha válida pero me estoy encontrando con problemas. Utilizo la librería moment.js para ello pero al tratar de convertirla a un objeto de tipo fecha, la trata internamente de forma incorrecta.

Inicialmente tengo:

```
var texto_fecha = '02/01/2020 00:10'; //es decir, 2 de enero de 2020
var fecha_inicial = new Date(texto_fecha); //aquí js coge su formato por defecto y comienza el problema.

var a = moment(fecha_inicial,'DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(a); //esto me sigue diciendo que la fecha es el 1 de febrero de 2020.
```

He visto que a menudo se hace "a mano", es decir, cambiando el orden del mes y del día. No obstante, me cuesta creer que una librería tan completa como es moment.js no tenga manera de hacerlo. Supongo que no habré dado con la manera de hacerlo.

Por favor, ¿alguien me puede ayudar en este sentido?

Lo que necesito concretamente es que recoja la fecha de forma correcta (2 de enero y no 1 de febrero) y hacerlo preferiblemente sin tener que alterar "a mano" dicha fecha, es decir, haciendolo únicamente con el objeto Date de js y moment.js

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que moment no recibe un segundo parámetro para formatear una fecha sino para traducirla, como primer argumento recibe una fecha ya sea en forma de objeto, numero, string, etc. Para formatear la fecha debes utilizar el método `format`.

**La forma correcta sería**:

```js
const texto_fecha = '02/01/2020 00:10'; //es decir, 2 de enero de 2020
const fecha_inicial = new Date(texto_fecha); //aquí js coge su formato por defecto y comienza el problema.

const a = moment(fecha_inicial).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Es necesario que entiendas que al convertir tu string en un objeto Date, no importa cuanto trates de traducirlo, porque has creado una fecha con un formato que se entiende como la RFC anglo. Asi que, no necesitas convertir tu string a fecha, y aunque tu string no es una RFC válida, moment lo traducirá y te dará solo un warning si no introduces el formato de entrada, pero la fecha será entendida (en este caso).

**De la siguiente manera**:

```js
const a = moment('02/01/2020 00:10', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('DD/MM/YYYY');

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

También podrías empezar a utilizar DayJS es mas moderno y eficiente que moment y lo hace la misma gente.

Espero que te sea de ayuda un saludo.